# How does this python regular expresssion work?

Tags: python, regex, expression, posix, python-re

I don't understand the result of this python regular expression "re.match("([abc])+", "abc")".
Can anybody explain how this regex works step by step?

```
import re
m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
print(m.groupdict())
print(m.groups())
print(m.group(1))
```

{}
('c',)
c

I expected the result of m.group(1) will be "a".

Comment: What's you actual intent? It's a little odd to be `+`-repeating a group. Typically that is done after the character class and inside of the group, not outside.